# Janela de dados deslocando no tempo (t)

Tags: r, loop, matriz

Quero fazer previsão do tipo Recursiva. Preciso a cada mes (t) deslocar a janela de dados do ultimo mes para frente em um periodo (periodo esse mensal, ou seja, t+1).

```
dados<-read.table("C:/Biomedica/Doença/evolmensal.txt", header=T, dec=",")
dados.ts <- ts(dados, start=c(1998,03), freq=12)
    periodo = window(dados.ts, start=c(1999,01),end=c(2007,12))
periodo

    stat=c(2008,01) 
dado_de_fora=window(dados.ts,start=stat)  

recurs.pred1=ts(0,start=stat,end=c(2014,10),frequency=12)
```

Segue o looping:

```
    for (t in 1:(length(dado_de_fora))) {
  reg.recur1=arima(window(periodo,end=c(2007,11+t)),order=c(1,0,1))
  recurs.pred1[t]=predict(reg.recur1,n.ahead=1)$pred
```

O problema que estou enfrentando é o de que quando t for igual a 2 a janela continua pegando apenas o periodo `end=c(2007,12)`ou seja, não caminha para `end=c(2008,01)`e assim por diante.

Quando rodo:

```
window(periodo,end=c(2007,11+3))
```

Deveria obter como dado final fevereiro de 2008

Answer (score 3):

Uma possível solução sem usar o `window`, utilizando os indexadores para pegar apenas uma parte da série temporal (os `[]`, se tiver outro nome, me avisem que corrijo!)

```
prev <- se <- NULL
for (i in 0:12) {
dados.ts <- ts(AirPassengers[1:(24 + i)], start = start(AirPassengers), frequency = frequency(AirPassengers))
prev[i + 1] <- predict(arima(dados.ts, c(1,0,1)), 1)$pred
se[i + 1] <- predict(arima(dados.ts, c(1,0,1)), 1)$se
}
```

Comment: Valeu, vou tentar! Parece que consegui, mas usei a window. Adicionei o comando 'extend=TRUE' dentro do window.

Answer (score 2):

> Quando rodo:
>
> `window(periodo,end=c(2007,11+3))`
>
> Deveria obter como dado final fevereiro de 2008

Respondendo esse ponto de somar meses:

Para obter o que você deseja nessa operação, você tem que operar com datas. Vou dar um exemplo com os pacotes `xts` e `lubridate`. Primeiro precisamos transformar seus números em um formato de data.

```
library(xts)
end <- c(2007, 11) # vetor de números
end <- paste(end, collapse="-") # transforma em texto
end <- as.yearmon(end) # transforma em data (formato yearmon)
```

Agora você pode somar meses:

```
end + 3/12
[1] "Fev 2008"
```

Você também pode voltar ao formato número usando as funções `year` e `month` (do lubridate) para extrair os números do ano e mês:

```
library(lubridate)
end <- end + 3/12 # adicionamos 3 meses ao vetor end
end <- c(year(end), month(end)) # transformamos o vetor end em número novamente
end
[1] 2008    2
```

Então você poderia trabalhar com algo do tipo. Agora, no seu caso específico, é mais fácil fazer o loop com um índice de números do que com datas - como o Rcoster colocou - mas pode ser que outra circunstância você de fato precise lidar com as datas.